# Getting Attribute Error: Nonetype has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

While executing my automation script in pycharm it is getting executed successfully but when I am trying to execute the same script in AWS Grid ec2 instance it is giving me error: Getting Attribute Error: Nonetype has no attribute 'strip'.

Comment: looks like you're doing ```strip()``` on some string which is ```None``` in this case. Can't assure anything without knowing the script.

Comment: But it is executing successfully on pycharm but throwing error on AWS grid